# How to extract body from a text file containing an e-mail [Enron Data Set]

Tags: java, email, dataset, jakarta-mail, email-parsing

I have enron e-mail data set as a folder, which contains e-mails in the form of text files, and I want to extract "body" part of those e-mails

The problem is, fields like sender's email, receiver's email are specified by To:, From: etc.
But Body does not start with any heading, it just starts after all the other fields have been specified.

now, a text file can contain many bodies (in case of email threads/conversation).
I want to extract the body(ies) from these files. Can javamail api be used, if yes, then how? It is just offline data set, in the form of text files in my hard disk drive, not on internet.

The file is like this-

```html
Message-ID: <16159836.1075855377439.JavaMail.evans@thyme>
Date: Fri, 7 Dec 2001 10:06:42 -0800 (PST)
From: heather.dunton@enron.com
To: k..allen@enron.com
Subject: RE: West Position
Mime-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=us-ascii
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit
X-From: Dunton, Heather </O=ENRON/OU=NA/CN=RECIPIENTS/CN=HDUNTON>
X-To: Allen, Phillip K. </O=ENRON/OU=NA/CN=RECIPIENTS/CN=Pallen>
X-cc: 
X-bcc: 
X-Folder: \Phillip_Allen_Jan2002_1\Allen, Phillip K.\Inbox
X-Origin: Allen-P
X-FileName: pallen (Non-Privileged).pst

 
Please let me know if you still need Curve Shift.

Thanks,
Heather
 -----Original Message-----
From:  Allen, Phillip K.  
Sent: Friday, December 07, 2001 5:14 AM
To: Dunton, Heather
Subject: RE: West Position

Heather,

Did you attach the file to this email?

 -----Original Message-----
From:  Dunton, Heather  
Sent: Wednesday, December 05, 2001 1:43 PM
To: Allen, Phillip K.; Belden, Tim
Subject: FW: West Position

Attached is the Delta position for 1/16, 1/30, 6/19, 7/13, 9/21


 -----Original Message-----
From:  Allen, Phillip K.  
Sent: Wednesday, December 05, 2001 6:41 AM
To: Dunton, Heather
Subject: RE: West Position

Heather,

This is exactly what we need.  Would it possible to add the prior day for each of the dates below to the pivot table.  In order to validate the curve shift on the dates below we also need the prior days ending positions.

Thank you,

Phillip Allen

 -----Original Message-----
From:  Dunton, Heather  
Sent: Tuesday, December 04, 2001 3:12 PM
To: Belden, Tim; Allen, Phillip K.
Cc: Driscoll, Michael M.
Subject: West Position


Attached is the Delta position for 1/18, 1/31, 6/20, 7/16, 9/24



 << File: west_delta_pos.xls >> 

Let me know if you have any questions.


Heather
```

Answer (score 0):

Please provide an example file, the most complex one if possible.
The job would be to programmatically open every file, parse its content, and extract email's bodies.
Where do you want to store it then ?
Which OS are you running ?

Comment: Couldn't post comment at time of posting (require 50 xp).

Comment: Example file is provided, what I want exactly is to get all the 'bodies' separately. (there are 5 bodies, as it is a conversation e-mail)
I have used Javamail api and used getContent() to extract the body, but it treats the body as a whole, (which starts two lines after X-Filename, to the end of the file)

Answer (score 0):

If each file is a single message in MIME format, you can use the JavaMail MimeMessage constructor that takes an InputStream.  You can then use the JavaMail APIs to extract the contents of the message.  See the JavaMail FAQ, javadocs, web site, specification, etc.